# How can I get MySQL to use the value returned by a function as a default?

Tags: mysql, mysql-5, phpmyadmin, default-value

I have a pre-existing table that has a column to that can hold a UUID.

I'd like to be able to define a default such that new rows coming in (from legacy systems) will still get a UUID defined, via the `UUID()` function -- is it possible to configure the default of a column to be a value returned by UUID (in a similar manner to how you can for the `UNIX_TIMESTAMP()` in phpMyAdmin)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using a [trigger](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/create-trigger.html)

You can't use functions as defaults in MySQL, [except for CURRENT_TIMESTAMP for TIMESTAMP columns](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/data-type-defaults.html)